# Не получается вставить в свойство content в css svg изображение

Tags: html, css

Не получается вставить в свойство content в css svg изображение.Буду рад любой помощи!

```js
span::after{
content: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg width="15" height="26" viewBox="0 0 15 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M13 2L2 13L13 24" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg>");
}
```

```html
<span>Здесь</span>
```

Comment: В одинарные кавычки возьмите значение `url()` [Пример тут](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt065gfn/)

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо!)Очень выручили!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

задать флекс и отцентровать

```
span::after {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```